# error in reading and writing in files

Tags: c++, file, class, object

**This program works but prints garbage values at the beginning (ch=2) and prints the same output twice.** 
I am using this for my project.It contains more data and there i used a single object instead of array of objects.It didnt work.*Each object of array stores a set of data.*

```
   #include<iostream>
   #include<fstream>
       using namespace std;
       class rw               //a class containing some data
       {
             public:
             int n;
             char a;
             };
       int main()

       {
           int i;
           rw r[2];           //an array of objects
           int ch;
           fstream f1;
           f1.open("file1.txt",ios::in|ios::out|ios::ate);
           cout<<"1-read,2-write";
           cin>>ch;
           f1.seekp(0,ios::beg);
           if(ch==1)//for saving
           {
                    r[0].n=1;
                    r[0].a='a';
                    f1.write((char*) &r[0],sizeof(r[0]));
                    r[1].n=2;
                    r[1].a='b';
                    f1.write((char*)&r[1],sizeof(r[1]));
                    }
           if(ch==2)//for reading
           {
                    f1.seekg(0,ios::beg);
           while(!f1.eof())
           {
                           i=0;
                           cout<<r[i].n<<r[i].a;
                           cout<<"\n";
                           f1.read((char*)&r[i],sizeof(r[i]));
                           i++;
                           }
                           }
                           system("pause");
                           return 0;
                           }
```

Comment: What do you mean `didn't work`, please can you elaborate on this? Does the program crash? Does it just not write out the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change following code

```
cout<<r[i].n<<r[i].a;
cout<<"\n";
f1.read((char*)&r[i],sizeof(r[i]));
```

to

```
f1.read((char*)&r[i],sizeof(r[i])); // Moved before printing
cout<<r[i].n<<r[i].a;
cout<<"\n";
```

You are outputting data then reading from the file, instead you should read and then print. Printing before reading is the reason for getting garbage in first run of loop. I think you moved the reading below to avoid double printing of last record. Continue reading to understand how to avoid double reading.

You should avoid using `while (!f1.eof())`, as it will print last data twice.
Better use `while(f1.read((char*)&r[i],sizeof(r[i])));`

Unrolling the eof version of loop for 2 inputs

```
while(!eof) // true
read first data
print first data
while(!eof) // true
read second data  // read all, but was succesful and eof not set
print second data
while(!eof)  // true
Try to read // Could not read, eof set
print data // Reprinting second data
while(!eof) // false
```

Comment: You are already reading in `while`, so you should not read it again inside loop.

Comment: I removed it..now it crashes

Comment: how does the loop terminate?

Comment: It crashes because side of r array is insufficient. Make it larger or don't increment i. Loop terminates when you fail to read more data from the file.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `while (!f1.eof())`, it will not work as you expect it to, because the `eofbit` flag isn't set until *after* you try to read from beyond the file. Instead do e.g. `while (f1.read(...))`.

Also be careful with a loop like this without bounds checking. If the file is not correct you might write out of bounds of the array `r`.

Comment: This should really be a comment as it doesn't answer the question (see @Mohit's answer above).

Comment: @cybermonkey It's not a *complete* answer in that it answers both of the OPs questions, because Mohits answer handled the other case but not this (at the point of me writing this answer).

Comment: It's still not an answer, and as far as I can see, the OP only asked one question (actually no question was asked!).

Comment: @cybermonkey Mohits answer, before quite extensive editing, answered the problem about the garbage data. My answer answered the problem about printing twice. Both problems are "asked" about in the first sentence of the question body. Just because someone else edits their answer to include what I wrote, *after* I wrote my answer, doesn't mean my answer is less valid.